# Convert string (T,T-1,T 1 ) to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a control which provide me the date selection in string format(T or T-1, T+1 etc ) and considering T as today date. I want to convert thestring selected Date(T or T-1, T+1) to DateTime.

Please Note that T(Today), T-1(Yesterday), T+1(Tommorrow) are received from the control and is in string format with one date at a time. Either T, T-1 or T+1 etc
I need to convert to T to something like 09/12/2013(for example with DD/MM/YYYY format)
T-1 to 08/12/2013 and T+1 to 10/12/2013.

Could you please suggest any standard/good approach to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please eloborate on what you mean by T,T-1, T+1. Could you give an example? Do you need multiple date outputs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not clear to me what you mean. Can you give an example of exactly what an input date looks like (it's format)? **Note:** You can use the _edit_ button under your original question to update it).

Comment: Your title and body are giving two different scenarios of what you want. Do you want to convert a string from format `T, T-1, T+1` or you want to convert a string from format `T`

Comment: My guess would be that the character T needs to be interpreted as today's date. Then the number afterwards indicates the offset. (Whether it might need to support codes other than 'T = Today', I have no idea). The OP needs to clarify.

Comment: I have added the required info.Please let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regex to both verify the input and to extract the operator (+/-) and the number of days:

```
var input = "T - 51";

// input ca be "[whitespace]T[whitespace][+-][whitespace][number][whitespace]
// (whitespace is optional at every position)
var re = new Regex(@"\s*[T]\s*(?<op>[+-])\s*(?<days>\d+)\s*");

// check if input is valid
var match = re.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    // extract operator and number of days
    var op = match.Groups["op"].Value;
    var days = int.Parse(match.Groups["days"].Value);

    // calculate resulting date
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(op == "+" ? days : -days);
}
```

Comment: @user3081925: Maybe just check if `input.Trim() == "T"` before the Regex stuff.